# how to resolve "could not find method gradlePluginPortal() for arguments[] on.."

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am attempting to create a build.gradle file for a Griffon 1.0.1 project. I have the gradle file successfully build standalone but it needs to be a subproject of a larger project with includes the documentation in AsciiDoc form. When I move the build.gradle file into the larger project, Gradle gives me an error on the build gradle file:

```
Build file 'D:\Projects\Decoder2\rrDecoder\decoder\build.gradle' line: 6

A problem occurred evaluating project ':decoder'.
> Could not find method gradlePluginPortal() for arguments [] on repository container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.

* Try:
```

I suspect that the error is something in the parent project folder, but I can't see anything wrong.
The settings.gradle file is:

```
rootProject.name = 'rrDecoder'
include 'decoder'
include 'doc'
```

Where should I be looking to find the cause of this error?

I have successfully built the project as a single project, but I get the error as soon as I make it a subproject. If I change into the the folder with the subproject and try to do a Gradle compile or run there, it still accesses the parent project and gives the same error. Somehow, Gradle is able to determine the project structure, even when the current directory is the subproject folder.

Environment is: Windows 11, Griffon 16.0.1, Java 1.8.0_372 (Azul), Gradle 3.5.1, Groovy 2.4.10

Comment: `gradlePluginPortal()` is a method called by default when processing project settings (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html). Have you removed the `settings.gradle` file from the subproject when you bring it into the multimodule project?

Comment: I had not removed it. I removed it and am still getting the same error.

Comment: I suppose the only thing left is your root `build.gradle` file. That will run before your child `build.gradle`. Does that have anything in it? I also see you are using a very old version of Gradle there. I would treat yourself to an upgrade if you can! As we're on v8.5 now, goodness knows how many bugs have been cleared in that time

Comment: The root project doesn't have build.gradle. I used Gradle 7.6.3 and that problem is gone, so the updated Gradle version has resolved it (though I still have other issues to work through). We should consider this problem resolved.